# How to get "subsubsections" in the table of contents if the document class is book?

Tags: sections-paragraphs

I want to use the `book` class for a thesis and need to provide the table of content with chapter-section-subsection-subsubsection, all four should be displayed.

Is there any trick to make it, as I only get chapter-section-subsection if I use the normal `\tableofcontents`?

Comment: `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}`,`\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can add syntax highlighting of code in you posts by selecting the text and clicking the button marked `{}`, or hit Ctrl + K. Inline code is placed between backticks (`\``), blocks are indented by four spaces.

Comment: @karlkoeller Probably a better fit, especially since it doesn't specifically mention the `report` class